# Conditional query on Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have one .rpt where the embedded sql query is a simple select from. The report is built by a separate desktop app, which builds up the conditions for the report by means of the GroupSelectionFormula, and ReplaceSelectionFormula. It's VB code. My issue would be slightly different results when running the report, versus running the SQL constructed with the where clause translated from the methods mentioned above. Is there another point of interaction that could affect the end results of the sql on Crystal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind this. The problem turned out to be a data fragmentation issue.